# How to generate an excel file using java which reads data from a database and the data should we spread into multiple sheets within the excel file

Tags: java, mysql, excel, apache-poi

I want that while writing the data into excel from database after 1000 rows the data should automatically move to next sheet.how will we write the  code(logic) in java

```
List<String> header = new ArrayList<String>();
             header.add("EmployeeId");
             header.add("EmployeeEmailId");
             header.add("EmployeeAddress");
             header.add("EmployeePhonenumber");
             header.add("EmployeePincode");


             int horizCount = 0;
             int verticalCount = 0;
             for ( String head : header ) {
                workSheet.addCell(new Label(verticalCount++,horizCount,head,headerFormat)); 
             } 
             horizCount = 1 ;
             for( Employee employee: uniqueStrings ){

                 verticalCount = 0;
                 workSheet.addCell(new Label(verticalCount++,horizCount,employee.getEmployeeId(),dataFormat));`enter code here`
                 workSheet.addCell(new Label(verticalCount++,horizCount,employee.getEmployeeEmailId(),dataFormat));
                 workSheet.addCell(new Label(verticalCount++,horizCount,employee.getEmployeeadddress(),dataFormat));
                 workSheet.addCell(new Label(verticalCount++,horizCount,employee.getEmployeephoneno(),dataFormat));
                 workSheet.addCell(new Label(verticalCount++,horizCount,employee.getEmployeepincode(),dataFormat));
                 horizCount++;
             }

             //write to the excel sheet
             workbook.write();

             //close the workbook
             workbook.close();
       }
       catch(FileNotFoundException e)
       {
           workbook.write();

           //close the workbook
           workbook.close();
           throw new IOException("File Not found exception occured."); 
       }
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried..

Comment: javascript != java ... If your question is not related to javascript, would you please remove the javascript tag

Comment: Track the current sheet, and the row count, then create a new sheet whenever you hit your threshold?

Answer (score 0):

From your code I am assuming you are creating the worksheet somewhere above for loop. Create a new worksheet in the loop if number of records written=1000. Some thing like this

```
             if ((horizCount % 1000) == 0) {

                // Create a new workSheet
                workSheet = new WorkSheet();
             }
```

Comment: Of course you need to Also add the code to add header to the sheet in to the if condition